# generating random samples with a PDF

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, sampling

I have the PDF of a distribution from which it is not possible to get a closed from for the CDF or inverse CDF. Is there a technique that would allow me to generate samples from this distribution using the PDF?

Comment: It depends. The normal density does not have a closed-form expression for the CDF or the inverse CDF but samples can nonetheless be generated via the Box-Muller method (among others). So, does your pdf have any nice properties that can be exploited?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a suggestion for the case where the density function is $0$ outside the interval $[a,b]$, and is bounded by $c$ on $[a,b]$. Use a random number generator to generate random points om the rectangle with base $[a,b]$ and height $c$. If the pdf is $f(x)$, discard all points $(x,y)$ such that $y\gt f(x)$. For each point you keep, record $x$.

Comment: My PDF in multivariate continuous and is everywhere positive so this might not work, but it does give me some ideas!

Comment: Multivariate is in principle not a problem, use a "box" instead of a rectangle. In practice, there is a problem, too high a proportion of the points gets rejected, so the process can become computationally inefficient. There are lots of additional tricks, you might want to look under rejection sampling.